# The compiler failed with error code 128

Tags: .net, iis-6

Any help will be appreciated in this matter. Everything was working fine in the server and sometimes goes off but comes back. No change in settings or code. I have IIS6

**The compiler failed with error code 128.**

Show Detailed Compiler Output:

c:\windows\system32\inetsrv> "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /t:library /utf8output /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\assembly\dl3\9c9bf6eb\3eedd736_2f8aca01\App_Web_lgr55t0b.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\assembly\dl3\272d69ce\7eba3e36_2f8aca01\App_WebReferences.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mobile\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Mobile.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.DataSetExtensions\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml.Linq\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.Linq.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel.Web\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\assembly\dl3\e25e52de\00ce3fe6_3622ca01\TimeShareWare.Data.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Data\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Data.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\assembly\dl3\3e4a21d6\009a615e_3b2bca01\WebAPI.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\assembly\dl3\ae306efc\4edd7836_2f8aca01\App_Code.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\assembly\dl3\71aef691\00bc672f_ad51ca01\Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Design\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Design.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\assembly\dl3\62e6b8e5\00983c5a_224cca01\AjaxControlToolkit.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Runtime.Serialization\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Core\3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Core.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IdentityModel\3.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IdentityModel.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.WorkflowServices\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.WorkflowServices.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\assembly\dl3\8513a4e8\008204eb_3622ca01\TimeShareWare.Data.DataAccess.DLL" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Services\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.Services.dll" /R:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\assembly\dl3\e1d92796\001f41f4_3522ca01\TimeShareWare.Utilities.DLL" /out:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.ftllmsly.dll" /D:DEBUG /debug+ /optimize- /win32res:"C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\q2sg3fsi.res" /w:4 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701 /warnaserror-  "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.ftllmsly.0.cs" "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\smvc_ws_sihot_tsw\b1f5e0d4\f962a7a6\App_Web_default.aspx.cdcab7d2.ftllmsly.1.cs"

Comment: I am getting this error for other websites
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\8cf8qthb.dll'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)

Comment: I've deployed a website to my hosting provider and currently getting this error. I take it there's not much I can do except contact them?

Comment: Refreshing the app pool in the server solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Suggest you deploy the site as a precompiled website, using either a web deployment project or using the "Publish" option on the context menu. This is a problem that occurs sometimes when a site has not been pre-compiled - I've never quite understood why but it is failing to find its own JIT-compiled assemblies for one or more of the pages and controls in your project.

Comment: Actually all the projects have been deployed using the "Publish" option from .NET

Answer (score 1):

I would try changing the identity of the app pool which the application is using to Local System. This worked for me recently, the strange thing was that we switched it back later and the site continued to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually happens when you update some aspx page so the application doesnt recicle the app pool. To force recicle you can just rename your web.config to web.config_ access you page it will drop an error missing the web.config then rename the file back to web.config

Works for me on localhost or shared host enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

I tried these suggestions and others from on-line, including moving the website to it's own app pool.

Only re-booting the server helped.

My issue happened after modifying a .cs file and re-publishing the website from VS2008 SP1.
But I'm not convinced that was the cause.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I had this exact problem and none of the solutions seemed to work.  I'm running two .NET 1.1 web apps and this compilation error occurred on one not the other. The error occurred just after I uploaded some new dlls.

But then I noted this line in [this KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/916451): "This problem occurs when a third-party component is running in the W3wp.exe process that has attached a console to the process. The Vbc.exe compiler process and the Csc.exe compiler process then inherit this console."

I checked the Users tab in task manager and sure enough there I was with status "Disconnected" on the console connected.  I forced a log off on my disconnected self and the app started correctly. Evidently I was the third-party process.

I had a feeling that a reboot wasn't needed because one of two apps was running.  But I also knew it wasn't the code I uploaded either since my app ran fine locally and all of the folders matched in a compare tool (i.e., I didn't forget to upload anything).